# UITableViewCell behaving strange

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I posted a thread earlier about a strange behavior when resizing UITableView for it to fit a keyboard. I want to simulate the same functionality as for when a user sends an SMS and the UITextField enters first responder (resizing the tableview and show keyboard).

The funny thing is that everything works great up to the point when I add a new row to the tableview (message). The keyboard remains in the right position but my UIToolBar moves to the bottom of the screen where its startingposition is.

I will demonstrate the scenario with the following pictures (this is a test-project):

[image]

This is the first state and everything works great. The Up-button will simulate the UITextField entering first responder, the Add-button will add an item to the tableview, and the Down-button will simulate the UITextField resigning first responder.

I first press the Up-button resulting in the following state:

[image]

And then I press the Add-button to add an item to the TableView resulting in the following (correct) state:

[image]

And everything is great, however, when I start adding subviews(buttons, labels, etc) to the UITableViewCell, hell breaks loose. It's hard to illustrate but the UIToolBar moves to the bottom of the screen as the picture next shows:

[image]

It is important to mention that I have created a UITableViewCell class and connected the label, shown in the picture above, to an outlet within this class.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

So my conclusion is that the problem lies within the Custom Cell and its subviews but I have not yet figured out where the problem is.

I would appreciate any suggestion or help to figure this out.

Many thanks
Robert

Comment: It is very hard to understand exactly what your problem is

Comment: Ill try to explain in better. I have a tableview and a toolbar, the first thing that I do is to move the toolbar up so that a keyboard will fit beneath it. Then I resize the tableview so that all the content fits above the toolbar (picture 2). Depending on if I use a custom cell or the "built in" the toolbar is strangly moved to the bottom if I use a custom cell and not if I'm using the built in. I don't want it to move at all and I need to use the custom cell.